# Probability that exactly two of first four events occur and event occurring infinitely often

Tags: probability, statistics

Let $A_1, A_2, · · · ,$ be a sequence of events of a sample space, not necessarily mutually exclusive.

$(a)$ Find an expression for the event that at most one of the first three events occurs. Hint: the event that “at least one of the first two events occurs” is expressed as $A_1 ∪ A_2$.

$(b)$ Find an expression for the event that exactly two of the first four events occur.

$(c)$ Interpret the event represented by $B_n =∪_{i=n} ^∞A_i$

$(d)$ We say that the sequence {$A_n$} occurs infinitely often if there exists an infinite sequence $n_i$ such that $A_{n_i}$ occurs for all $i$.

Show that the event that {$A_n$} occurs infinitely often is represented by $O =\cap_{n=1}^∞ B_n =\cap_{n=1}^∞∪_{i=n}^∞A_i$. (That is $B_n =∪_{i=n}^∞A_i$).

My attempts:

$(a)$ "At most one of the first three events occurs" is equivalent to saying the complement of "at least two of the first three events occur".
And thus, this could be expressed as: $(A_1A_2∪A_2A_3∪A_3A_1)^c$, where $A_1A_2 = A_1 \cap A_2$ and so on.

$(b)$ I'm not sure about this part, but is "exactly two of the first four events occur" equivalent to saying the complement of ("at most one of the first four events occur intersection at least three of the first four events occur")?
And if so, how is it written as an expression?

$(c)$ $B_n =∪_{i=n} ^∞A_i$.
So for $n=1, B_1 = ∪_{i=1} ^∞A_i = A_1∪A_2∪A_3∪...$
And for $n=2, B_2 = ∪_{i=2} ^∞A_i = A_2∪A_3∪A_4∪...$
So is this the union of the first $i$ events excluding the first $n-1$ events?

$(d)$ I don't know how to go about this. Any help please?

Comment: when I had this assignment, I remember doing something similar for $(a)$, I don't think the complement interpretation is correct in $(b)$ as for $(d)$ you have the Borelli-Cantelli lemma https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borel%E2%80%93Cantelli_lemma

Comment: Borel-Cantelli doesn't help you with (d). A hint would be: Try to write up what it means for an element to lie in $\cap_{n=1}^{\infty} B_n$ using quantifiers. I.e. $x\in \cap_{n=1}^{\infty} B_n$ if and only if $\forall n; x\in B_n$. Now, try continuing this line of logic to try to tie it together with the existence of the $n_i$.

Comment: @WoolierThanThou so $x \in B_n$ for all $n$ implies that $x \in ∪_{i=n} ^∞A_i$ which in turn implies $x \in A_i$, for some $i$, $i=${$n,.... $} thus there is a sequence $n_i$ such that $A_{n_i}$ occurs for all $i$. Is that correct?

Comment: @xX A C E Xx is part $(c)$ correct?

Comment: @JOJO Yes. You've now proven that if $x\in \cap_n B_n$, then there exists some seqeunce $n_{i}(x)$ such that $x\in A_{n_i(x)}$ for all $i$. Now, you need to go the other way.